# Webstorm IDE and mocha tests using global.expect

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, bdd, webstorm

I currently run the following command to run my mocha tests:

```
./node_modules/.bin/mocha --require ./my.js
```

and in the js file, I am using sinon and expect for SpyOn...

```
global.expect = require('must');
global.sinon = require('sinon');
```

How do I configure the Mocha task runner to use this external file.
Using `--require ./my.js` I still see `ReferenceError: spyOn is not defined`

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0):

Required modules are resolved relative to the working directory specified in "Working directory" field of Mocha Run/Debug configuration.

Here is the configuration that works for me:

```
working directory: C:\WebstormProjects\mocha_sinon
Mocha package: C:\WebstormProjects\mocha_sinon\node_modules\mocha
Extra options: --require ./with_req/util.js
Test directory: C:\WebstormProjects\mocha_sinon\with_req
```

My spec file:

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var should = require('should');

describe('EventEmitter', function(){
    describe('#emit()', function(){
        it('should invoke the callback', function(){
            var spy = sinon.spy()
                , emitter = new EventEmitter;

            emitter.on('foo', spy);
            emitter.emit('foo');
            spy.called.should.equal.true;
        })
        })
})
```

util.js;

```
global.sinon = require('sinon');
```